# Why Is My PHP Page View Tracker Not Working

Tags: php, sql, tracking

I have a simple page view tracker that uses a combination of PHP and MySQL to keep a running tally of the number of times the page has been refreshed. There is no complex cookies I just needed to know the raw number refreshes that occur.

It looks like this...

```
$link = mysql_connect('**********', '*********', '***********');
if (!$link)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("**********", $link);

$query = mysql_query("select value from settings where title like 'search_number'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$search_number = $result["value"];
$new_search_number = $search_number + 1;
mysql_query("update settings set value='$new_search_number' where title like 'search_number'");
```

This code appears to work in all the tests I was capable of running but on the live site it returns ridiculously high numbers. We average 400-500 queries a day according to yahoo, "we use search boss", but the page tracker reports 8900+ queries a day. Google analytic confirms yahoo's number. I don't see how this code could fail due to its simplicity. I was hoping somebody could shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: I think we're going to need to know a lot more about your site/page architecture and how this bit of script gets called. If it's in being included/required you might be calling it multiple times per page? On a side note: You can definitely combine those two queries to just something like: "update settings set value = value + 1 where title like 'search_number'". Not sure about MySQL syntax exactly, but in MSSQL it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots will hit your page more often than you might think.  You can compare to your server logs, and I suspect you will see that many requests for your page.

Also, Google Analytics works client-side, requires JavaScript, and does not always run.  This has been predicted to account for as many as 10% or so page views.  The bulk of the difference though is that Google Analytics filters out a lot of random hits from bots, as hardly any bots even run the analytics code.

On another note, the way you are doing your queries is a bit precarious.  I recommend learning how to do prepared queries with PDO, to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Update the value direcly in MySQL otherwise concurring scripts will overwrite each others values:

```
mysql_query("update settings set value=value + 1 where title like 'search_number'");
```